# pip install success but ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip

My directory structure is:

```
package/
  __init__.py
  setup.py
```

setup.py is:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name="package",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
)
```

When I run `pip install ./package`, the install successes:

```
Processing ./package
Installing collected packages: package
  Running setup.py install for package ... done
Successfully installed package-0.0.1
```

However, I can't import it:

```
In [1]: import package
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-f73d57b147d4> in <module>()
----> 1 import package

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'package'
```

How to create a package and import it?

Comment: change `__init.py` to `__init__.py`. This will make it a package and allow you to import it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that the `pip` command really is the pip that goes along with the Python installation you are using? If you run Python using e.g.

```
python3 mymodule.py
```

you should invoke pip using

```
python3 -m pip install ./package
```

The `-m pip` ensures you that you get the pip that goes along with the specified Python installation.